# Amazon Lex : How to get Elicitation value of a slot in Lambda function (Python)?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have built a bot in which I am using slots to capture the customer's input. One of the slots is CheckinDate where I ask a user to enter a check-in date. I am using Amazon.Date slot type.

**Problem**
The user can enter a date in words e.g. eleventh of Jan 2022 or next friday. CheckinDate slot store the value entered by the customer. When we click on inspect, this value is stored by lex bot in a proper date format as you can see in the following picture.
[image: ElicitationValue]

My only concern is that I want to get that elicitation value in my Lambda function (Python). The CheckinDate slot stores the same date or phrase entered by the customer.

I would appreciate if someone guide me with proper guidance step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a look at the payload that Lex sends through to the Lambda function to find what you're looking for.

Here's a quick extract from the Lex event that's passed through to a Python lambda supporting a test intent:-

```
   "inputTranscript":"sunday",
   "interpretations":[
      {
         "intent":{
            "slots":{
               "Date":{
                  "shape":"Scalar",
                  "value":{
                     "originalValue":"sunday",
                     "resolvedValues":[
                        "2022-04-10"
                     ],
                     "interpretedValue":"2022-04-10"
                  }
               }
            },
```

In this example the user is asked to enter a date. The user enters `Sunday` as the response. The payload sent through to the Lambda function contains the user's raw input as well as the value that Lex has interpreted based on the given data type for the slot. In this example that's `AMAZON.Date`.

This should help you perform whatever custom business logic you need to apply.